# VS2008 Website project : Unable to get dependencies for project reference

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, web, vs-web-site-project

I'm having a few issues building a website project (those without a project file) in VS2008. My website references another project that contains the business logic for the application which itself references third-party DLLs.

Now when I add the business logic project reference to the website, the project DLLs are copied across to the BIN directory of the website but none of the third party DLLs that are required for it to run. I've ensured that 'copy always' is set in my business logic dll references.

I recently upgraded my system to VS2008 9.0.30729.4462 QFE as part of a migration to Team Foundation Server 2010 and the problems only seem to have started since this upgrade.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually reference the 3rd party dlls in your project.  The copy feature in VS only copys the project assembly when it is referenced.

Comment: That's what I thought - but my website project was pulling through all dependent DLLs too, but for some reason it's now not doing so. I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anyone has something else to contribute before I mark this as the answer. Thanks